# How do I put a checksum in a script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting, checksum

I was (am) having trouble installing [Eagle](http://web.cadsoft.de/ftp/eagle/program/7.2/eagle-lin-7.2.0.run) on my Linux (debian 8 jessie)
computer. I was reading the installer script, when i noticed there is a checksum for the install script in the install script?

I modified 1 character in the script, in a comment, and suddenly I was getting

> Checksum error in './eagle-lin-7.2.0.run'

How does that work? Wouldn't you need to know the checksum before putting it in the script? It seems paradoxical to me. Can someone please explain how a checksum for the entire script can be placed in the script?

This particular checksum is MD5.

Comment: If you can make a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), I'd guess might be possible. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193993/are-there-algorithms-for-putting-a-digest-into-the-file-being-digested (in particular the last section of the second answer)

Comment: learning some new words...

Comment: How exactly have you modified the script ? The checksum is for the archive that follows the script (everything after the line `__DATA__`) so I don't see how modifying the script itself would have any effect on archive checksum. I just downloaded the installer and deleted all commented lines from the script with `sed -i` and it installed fine afterwards.

Comment: @muru No, [you can't make a script that contains its own cryptographic hash](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9910/is-it-theoretically-possible-to-construct-a-string-that-contain-its-own-hash-val). It's possible, mathematically speaking, but actually finding one would require to run all the computers now on Earth for longer than the universe has existed.

Comment: @Gilles agreed.

Comment: When calculating the hash, you can ignore the line that contains the hash. E.g. `CALC=$(grep -v CHECKSUM= $0 | md5sum)`

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded this installer and took a peek.  Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
#!/bin/bash

MD5=1fe8463da9322ad9c966a57b92569a52

# The required tools:
SED=sed
MD5SUM=md5sum
CUT=cut
DATA="$SED -e '1,/^__DATA__$/d' '$0'"

# Check archive integrity:
test `eval $DATA | $MD5SUM | $CUT -d " " -f 1` = $MD5 || {
  echo "Checksum error in '$0'" >&2
  exit 1
  }

# ...

exit 0
# Everything after the next line is a .tar.bz2 file
__DATA__
[a binary blob finishes the file]
```

This runs `sed -e '1,/^__DATA__$/d'` on the script itself, which deletes all lines from the beginning (line 1) to the `__DATA__` line, leaving just the binary behind.  The binary is then run through `md5sum` to get the checksum, `cut` then formats it to contain just the checksum itself (no filename), and then it is compared to the hard-coded checksum from earlier in the script.

The `test` statement returns true when the MD5 matches and false when it does not match.  The `||` will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) when the test is true, meaning it stops evaluation.  The bracketed stanza will only run when the test is false.

Since you likely didn't (intentionally) touch anything after that `__DATA__` line, it's probably your text editor's fault.  I suspect it added a space or blank line or it converted between DOS and UNIX line formats ([learn more about newlines at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

Another possibility is that the download failed and you have a corrupted file.  If this is not a concern, merely remove the `exit 1` line from that MD5 test stanza and the installer should work just fine.

(This script is not well written, so I am not at all surprised that you had to modify it to make it work.)